# Почему это правило блокирует все соединения iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables

В этой статье посвященной защите от дудос атак:
https://javapipe.com/blog/iptables-ddos-protection/
есть правило:

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --syn -j CT --notrack
```

Можете пожалуйста объяснить, что оно делает? И почему оно у меня блокирует абсолютно все соединения? Даже ssh, приходится ребутать хост.

У меня debian 9, версия iptables v1.6.0

Comment: Правило блокирует запись информации о соединении в таблицу отслеживания состояний соединений (conntrack). А все ломает видимо из за того, что где то в другом месте заданы правила основанные на состоянии соединений явно (--state) или не явно (различные виды NAT и другие специальные модули) и эти правила перестают корректно работать, так как состояний у соединения больше нет

Comment: определённости ради, «блокируется абсолютно всё» только при указании одного правила или всех трёх из статьи? и есть ли другие правила в таблицах?

Comment: @Fat-Zer не только. у меня куча правил уже есть. я не проверял это правило на чистом iptables

Comment: @Mike а зачем вообще не записывать в conntrack?

Comment: Потому что он не резиновый. И при большом количестве соединений он переполняется

Comment: @Mike правильно ли я вас понял. если сделать соединению --notrack, то модуль -m conntrack --ctstate в любых других правилах срабатывать не будет и все это ради оптимизации? но как это тогда все работает, conntrack или state очень часто нужно использовать, даже в той статье от ddos используеются правила conntrack

Comment: Лично я вообще никогда правила ctstate не использую, особенно для tcp. Никто вас флудить продолжениями соединений, без syn не будет, потому как они и так будут отброшены ядром за неимением записей в таблицах соединений (tcp стека, не iptables). В большинстве случаев, что бы что то заблокировать достаточно дропнуть syn пакет и все.

Comment: @Mike а как тогда прописать такое правило без ctstate: -A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT ?

Comment: А зачем оно нужно ? Я предпочитаю что бы было разрешено все, кроме того, что явно запрещено. А явно запрещаю я (из tcp) только SYN пакеты, кроме некоторых портов, на которые нужен доступ. При такой политике ответные пакеты на соединения инициируемые самой машиной никогда под запрет не попадут

Comment: @Mike огромное спасибо за объяснение! это и правда звучит здорово с точки зрения оптимизации. Скажите, а для протоколов udp и icmp есть альтернатива, чтобы тоже не использовать conntrack?

Comment: На UDP там служб то всего ничего, dns, ntp, nfs по портам можно разрулить. Десяток правил на запрет конкретных портов, которые снаружи не нужны и все. Хотя можно даже попробовать полный запрет кроме 53 и 123 входящего/исходящего и дальше посмотреть не сломалось ли что. С icmp аналогично, решить должна ли машина на ping отвечать и прикрыть чисто его запрос, если хотите

Comment: @Mike открывать 53 безопасно? в данный момент у меня входящие соединения по UDP полностью закрыты, вообще все порты. есть только одно правило -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT, чтобы поддерживать исходящие соединения DNS. но там вряд ли они дают значительную нагрузку.., в данной ситуации нормально будет оставить conntrack?

Comment: зависит от того, какова реальная нагрузка и нельзя ли создать какую либо нагрузку на сервер, которая вызовет за собой dns запросы. Например на вас сыплются запросы на коннект ssh, которые вы пропускаете в sshd. Он для того что бы записать в лог от кого была попытка коннекта пытается определить имя хоста по ip, т.е. ищет запись в dns... Но да, видимо оставляйте, если будут проблемы придется делать тупо -p udp -s 53 -j ACCEPT но это конечно совершенно не то же самое.

Comment: @Mike ты писал "А явно запрещаю я (из tcp) только SYN пакеты, кроме некоторых портов". Кстати, а что если придет вредоносный пакет нового соединения без флага syn? Так ведь можно будет запрет обойти

Comment: SYN это пакет открытия соединения. Без него соединение не создастся

Comment: @Mike для чего тогда в той статье было сказано прописать iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp ! --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP. даже я на своем опыте помню дудос был пакетами NEW но не syn. я просто уточняю, не хочу открыть возможность дудосерам

Comment: Ну соединений они точно не создадут и следов в таблицах ядра не оставят. На сколько такой дос опасен с точки зрения нагрузки на систему хз